# Can multiple taps be defined on a single Spring XD stream

Tags: spring-xd

For Spring XD 1.3.1, using Rabbit MQ transport, distributed.

Looking for clarification on how Spring XD taps work for metrics.
I need to know if one stream can be tapped multiple times so that each message through the primary stream will be sent to each of the active defined taps.

The scenario is a stream with a rabbit source that has processing before delivering to a sink, such as mongo.  This stream is tapped to an alternate sink.  We also want to create multiple metrics on this stream including an aggregate counter and a couple of field value counters that will keep metrics on total messages and message by type looking a different fields in the source message (which os on JSON).

The documentation is unclear on if each tap gets a copy of the message.

In testing, the first tap is getting all messages, but none of the field value or aggregate counters seem to be getting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, A stream can have multiple taps. Here is an [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-samples/tree/master/analytics-dashboard). Internally, XD uses the message bus to [bind to a pub-sub resource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/plugins/AbstractMessageBusBinderPlugin.java#L304) (transport dependent). For example, using Rabbit MQ transport, a Fanout exchange is [created](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-messagebus-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/integration/rabbit/RabbitMessageBus.java#L710) for each potential tap point in a stream. Binding a queue to that exchange is performed lazily, i.e., when the tap stream is created. You should see the corresponding exchanges and queue bindings for each tap in the Rabbit admin console.

I'm not sure why you are not seeing messages in all taps. Keep in mind that taps should always be deployed (after the target stream is created but before the target stream is deployed), any data in the stream before the tap is deployed will not be consumed by the tap.